# Uncaught ReferenceError: var is not defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two textarea which starts on empty value.
Then when I fill the first textarea with id "postcrudo" I want that the next textarea (with id "posthecho") getthe same value as the first, and also show the same. Like a two way binding, like AngularJS, but only with JavaScript and jQuery.

This is the JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
      $("#postcrudo").val(function(){
        algo = this;
      });
      postHecho = postCrudo;
      console.log("OK!");
    });
  });
</script>
```

and this the HTML:

```
<body>        
  <div style="width:700px;float:left;">
    <p>Post crudo:</p>
    <p><textarea cols="100" maxlength="99999" name="postCrudo" id="postcrudo" rows="60"></textarea></p>
  </div>
  <div style="width:700px;float:left;">
    <p>Post pasado:</p>
    <p><textarea cols="100" maxlength="99999" name="postHecho" id="posthecho" rows="60"></textarea></p>
  </div>
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
  <p><input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" /></p>        
</body>
```

The error in Chrome console is:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: postCrudo is not defined

Comment: I don't see any declaration for the variable `postCrudo`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

https://jsfiddle.net/a4nmto6t/1/

Just get the value of the first textarea and change the value of the second to that:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        var postCrudoVal = $("#postcrudo").val();
        $("#posthecho").val(postCrudoVal);
        console.log("OK!");
    });
});
```

Neither `postHecho` nor `postCrudo` are declared (by you**), and even if they were, assigning one of them to the other does not do what you want. You have to assign the **`value` of the first textarea to the `value` of the second textarea** using (in this case) jQuery selectors, because they ARE the ones referencing the DOM elements (the textareas).

** Elements that have an id are set as global 'variables' by default, but you shouldn't use them; it is instead suggested that you either use the DOM API to find elements or use jQuery (which uses the DOM API behind the scenes).

Comment: Thanks all for helping me. Finally I've decided to use AngularJS to handle this problem. The 2 way data binding is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Your element id `postcrudo` is all lowercase. `postCrudo` is indeed not defined

This line`postHecho = postCrudo;` makes no sense, I think you're trying to do this:

```
$('#posthecho').val($('#postcrudo').val())
```

Comment: The element ID and the jQuery selector match - this is not the problem.

Comment: The jQuery part is fine. Me and the error are referring to `postHecho = postCrudo` what do you expect that to do?

Comment: I expect it to fail, but not for the reason you have implied. Your first line refers to the element ID which is not relevant. See above.

Answer (score 0):

There is no declaration of `postCrudo` so it is undefined.  Also why would you want to try and do this yourself instead using something like AngularJS to handle data bindings.  You are essentially doing more work for no reason.  Plus you have to handle all aspects of 2 way data binding manually.  To me there is smarter ways to do this.

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript syntax is case sensitive.

```
`postHecho = postCrudo;`
```

Should be:

```
`postHecho = postcrudo;`
```

Comment: `postcrudo` is not defined either.